# web service consumer soap fault extraction

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule4

I am using web service consumer and calling a soap service and it will return below soap fault incase of number of hits reaches more than the limit. When the soap fault is caught in the error handler under the type WSC:SOAP_FUALT, I want to read the faultstring and if it is "Maximum request limit reached, please try again later.", I dont want to consider it as failure and point the payload for retry.

So please let me know how to extract the fault string inorder to put a check on it.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
        <faultcode>Internal Server Error</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Maximum request limit reached, please try again later.</faultstring>
    </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
```

</soapenv:Envelope>

Answer (score 1):

The soap fault message returned by Web Service Consumer is stored within the `errorMessage` field in the `error` of the flow.
So you can use `error.errorMessage.payload.Envelope.Body.Fault.faultstring` to access that string in your error handler block, and use it in the `when` condition of the error handler itself to execute that handler when this message matches the required criteria. For example:

[image]

XML Code:

```xml
<on-error-continue enableNotifications="true"
    logException="true" doc:name="On Error Continue"
    doc:id="38283c80-4c20-46da-85e3-f47d5d5755b7" type="WSC:SOAP_FUALT"
    when="#[(error.errorMessage.payload.Envelope.Body.Fault.faultstring default '') startsWith ('Maximum request limit reached')]">
    <logger message="Error message caught by the error handler: #[error.errorMessage.payload.Envelope.Body.Fault.faultstring]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="1f329e43-d401-412f-9479-f58bef4089c4" />
</on-error-continue>
```

Comment: In Some cases when SOAP fault does not return and when I return custom error, that time the error payload does not contain Envelope.Body.Fault.faultstring and so this expression evaluation itself is failing in this case, so please let me know how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Failing with what error? I thought this should not fail even it the path does not exist and simply return false

Comment: I am getting below error, ya ideally it should work even if the path does not exist but it is not working like that org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : "You called the function 'AnonymousFunction' with these arguments: 
  1: Null (null)
  2: String ("Maximum request limit reached")

But it expects arguments of these types:
  1: String
  2: String


1| error.errorMessage.payload.description startsWith ('Maximum request limit reached')

Comment: I have updated the code to handle that. I just checked the helper function for `startsWith` only came in Mule 4.4. I just added a `default ''`. That will send a blank string to `startsWith` and will also not effect the result

Comment: Now it works but when I try to consume the error message from my process api, I am not finding the error message in #[error.description]

Comment: The error description will have the description of the Mule error.  It will not have anything from the response from the soap ws. To get the payload containing that you need to access it from `error.errorMessage.payload`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple DataWeave expression to extract the string:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload.Envelope.Body.Fault.faultstring
```

Output:

```
Maximum request limit reached, please try again later.
```